# Why can I not get the BufferedReader to work inside a new Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, bufferedreader

I have created a thread that should allow the user to input a string of characters into the command line and this should save, on a new line, to a file, called user_input.txt.

I managed to make it work while on the main thread, but I need to make it happen within a Thread.

Here is my code for the Thread object:

```
//Importing
//Input
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
//File writing
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class FileInputThread implements Runnable
{
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("FileInputThread running");
        //Creating Instances of InputStreamReader and BufferedReader
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader keyboardInput = new BufferedReader(input);

        //Finding/Creating File
        File file = new File("/Users/jakecarr/Documents/University/Year 2/Semester 1" +
        "/ECM2414 Software Development/Workshop 3/user_input.txt");

        try {
            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            //Creating instances of FileWriter and BufferedWriter
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            //Creating Date object
            Date date;

            //Output
            System.out.println("Type what you want to write to file");
            System.out.println("Please type 'ESC' to exit");

                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Inside While loop");
                    String string = keyboardInput.readLine();
                    //Checks if user types in ESC to stop program
                    if (string.equals("ESC")) {
                        System.out.println("You are finished");
                        break;
                    }

                    //Writing the input to the file
                    bw.write(string);
                    bw.newLine();
                    //Flushes strings on buffered reader to the hard drive
                    bw.flush();
                }
            System.out.println("Writing to file complete");


        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Right now, it seems to do all the println methods, I just doesn't allow you to type anything in at the command line when it comes to the keyboardInput.readLine(); and that is where it seems to get stuck!

I would be grateful for any help!

Thank you.

Comment: `seems to get stuck` what does that mean? U getting any exception?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. All my input gets saved to the specified file and program exits when I type ESC and press Enter. Note that you have to press Enter before you type in ESC. In other words, ESC has to be in a new line.

Comment: this is possible that main thread is working with `System.in` too, would you share the main method code too!?